# Getting the New Map When the FocusMapChanged Event Fires

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-10.2, vb.net

Normally, in ArcMap, when an event handler to catch the FocusMapChanged event is set up, and a new map (data frame) is activated, when the event fires, a reference to the FocusMap returns the map that is being activated. BUT, when the currently active map is removed from the document, when the event fires, a reference to the FocusMap returns the map that is being removed! What?! This behaviour is not helpful to me.

Here's code that displays a message box with the name of the Focus Map whenever the FocusMapChanged event fires...

```vb
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI

Public Class test_FocusMapChanged
    Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    Private m_FocusMapChanged
    Private activeViewEventsPL As IActiveViewEvents_Event

    Private Sub ActiveViewEventsHandler(ByVal map As IMxDocument)
        activeViewEventsPL = TryCast(map.PageLayout, IActiveViewEvents_Event)

        m_FocusMapChanged = New IActiveViewEvents_FocusMapChangedEventHandler(AddressOf FocusMapChanged)
        AddHandler activeViewEventsPL.FocusMapChanged, m_FocusMapChanged
    End Sub
    Private Sub FocusMapChanged()
        MsgBox(My.ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.FocusMap.Name)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
        ActiveViewEventsHandler(My.ArcMap.Document)
    End Sub
```

Does anyone have any ideas of how to get around this and get a reference to the newly activated map rather than the removed map?

Comment: There should be two events fired: activate the map being removed so it can be removed, then there should be no active map... perhaps the 2nd event is bailing on Null Reference *My.ArcMap.Document.ActiveView.FocusMap ==  null;*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I ended up contacting Esri support about this... This can be worked around by wiring up the ItemDeleted event to the PageLayout. Then the ItemDeleted event will be fired whenever a map is deleted.

This gets me what I want:

```vb
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto
Imports ESRI.ArcGIS.ArcMapUI

Public Class test_FocusMapChanged
    Inherits ESRI.ArcGIS.Desktop.AddIns.Button
    Private m_ItemDeleted
    Private m_FocusMapChanged
    Private activeViewEventsPL As IActiveViewEvents_Event
    Shared theDataFrame

    Private Sub ActiveViewEventsHandler(ByVal map As IMxDocument)
        activeViewEventsPL = TryCast(map.PageLayout, IActiveViewEvents_Event)

        m_FocusMapChanged = New IActiveViewEvents_FocusMapChangedEventHandler(AddressOf FocusMapChanged)
        AddHandler activeViewEventsPL.FocusMapChanged, m_FocusMapChanged

        m_ItemDeleted = New IActiveViewEvents_ItemDeletedEventHandler(AddressOf ItemDeleted)
        AddHandler activeViewEventsPL.ItemDeleted, m_ItemDeleted
    End Sub
    Private Sub FocusMapChanged()
        theDataFrame = My.ArcMap.Document.FocusMap
    End Sub
    Private Sub ItemDeleted(ByVal item As Object)
        Dim pMapFrame As IMapFrame = item
        If pMapFrame.Map Is theDataFrame Then
            MsgBox(My.ArcMap.Document.FocusMap.Name)
        Else

        End If
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnClick()
        ActiveViewEventsHandler(My.ArcMap.Document)
    End Sub
End Class
```

I had to keep track of the map when the FocusMapChanged event occurs because if the active map is deleted the FocusMapChanged event fires first, and then the map is removed; so if the active map when the FocusMapChanged event fires is the same as the map being removed in the ItemDeleted event, then I want my code to run.